# Prove $\ker T=\ker S, \operatorname{Im}T= \operatorname{Im}S$, $T \ne S$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given: $V$ is a linear space and $S,T: V \rightarrow V$ are a linear transformations.

> If $\ker T=\ker S$ and $ \operatorname{Im}T =  \operatorname{Im}S$, give an example which makes $T \ne S$.

I thought about taking $V =\mathbb R^2$ , $T(x,y) = (x,y) ,S(x,y) = (2x,2y)$

Which if I take $(1,1) \in V$ then

$T(1,1) = (1,1)$

$S(1,1) = (2,2)$

But because $Im$ is a sub-space to V then I can take scalars $a,b \in R$ and say $a(1,1) = b(2,2)$ which makes it $ImT = ImS$

Then I do the same for $Ker$ (take same vectors) and say that they equal to zero and I get $KerT =  KerS$

And now because  $T(x,y) = (x,y) \ne S(x,y) = (2x,2y)$ because $(x,y) \ne (2x,2y)$ then $T \ne S$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works. More generally the group of automorphisms of $V$ provides you with infinitely many examples. Indeed, any automorphism $\varphi:V\to V$ satisfies $\ker \varphi=\{\mathbf 0\}$ and $\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}\im\varphi=V$.

In other words, any two distinct invertible $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ define linear maps $S,T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ given by
\begin{align*}
S(v)&=Av & T(v)&=Bv
\end{align*}
These two maps satisfy $\ker S=\ker T=\{\mathbf 0\}$ and $\im S=\im T=\Bbb R^n$ but $S\neq T$.

Comment: Thanks Brian! I love your answers!

Answer (score 2):

it seems ok, but you should give a better explanation for why the images and kernels are equal. In fact, why won't you just compute the kernels explicitly? it's quite easy. Then compute the images (either directly from the definition, or deduce they are equal by other means). What you wrote above is not really clear. One more (tiny) remark: to show that $T\ne S$, you can be a bit more explicit and to-the-point, by writing $T(1,1)=(1,1)\ne (2,2)=S(1,1)$.